# Partial blur effect on image, javafx

Tags: javafx, imageview, javafx-8, blur, motion-blur

I have a specific problem, that I was trying to find all over the Internet, but with no luck.The user will chose a model of a man(image view) and by moving its position, the blur effect will appear from up to down/ right to left on the man. Basically, I need to use blur effect on an image view, but with the option to set the part of the image that I want to be blurred.

[something like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5lTut.jpg)

https://www.freepik.com/free-photo/young-man-walking_1214201.htm'>Designed by Freepik

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you want a moving ImageView which is blurred at a specific part. For this you could set to ImageView to movable using onTouch events.
For blurring the image, you could use some hacky techniques or use Renderscript which blurs image very efficiently. It is described [here](https://plus.google.com/+MarioViviani/posts/fhuzYkji9zz?utm_source=Android%20Weekly&utm_campaign=0ebb6e887b-Android_Weekly_103&utm_medium=email&utm_term=0_4eb677ad19-0ebb6e887b-337837333) by Mario Viviani.

The code to blur images:

```
public Bitmap blurBitmap(Bitmap bitmap) {

//Let's create an empty bitmap with the same size of the bitmap we want to blur
Bitmap outBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight(), Config.ARGB_8888);

//Instantiate a new Renderscript
RenderScript rs = RenderScript.create(getApplicationContext());

//Create an Intrinsic Blur Script using the Renderscript
ScriptIntrinsicBlur blurScript = ScriptIntrinsicBlur.create(rs, Element.U8_4(rs));

//Create the in/out Allocations with the Renderscript and the in/out bitmaps
Allocation allIn = Allocation.createFromBitmap(rs, bitmap);
Allocation allOut = Allocation.createFromBitmap(rs, outBitmap);

//Set the radius of the blur
blurScript.setRadius(25.f);

//Perform the Renderscript
blurScript.setInput(allIn);
blurScript.forEach(allOut);

//Copy the final bitmap created by the out Allocation to the outBitmap
allOut.copyTo(outBitmap);

//recycle the original bitmap
bitmap.recycle();

//After finishing everything, we destroy the Renderscript.
rs.destroy();

return outBitmap;
}
```

[image: Output Image]

**2. Use Library**

You could use the [Dali Library](https://github.com/patrickfav/Dali) which does all the heavy lifting of RenderScript internally and implements blur easily.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Consider putting two copies of the image into a `StackPane`, applying a blur to one of them. Then just apply clips to each one so that you see half of one image and half of the other:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.ScrollPane;
import javafx.scene.effect.GaussianBlur;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class PartiallyBlurredImage extends Application {

    private final Image image = new Image("https://www.nasa.gov/sites/default/files/thumbnails/image/pia22226.jpg");
    private final double width = 600 ;
    private final double height = 800 ;


    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        ImageView plainImage = createImageView();

        ImageView blurredImage = createImageView();
        GaussianBlur blur = new GaussianBlur(20);       
        blurredImage.setEffect(blur);


        plainImage.setClip(new Rectangle(0, 0, width/2, height));
        blurredImage.setClip(new Rectangle(width/2, 0, width/2, height));

        StackPane partiallyBlurredImage = new StackPane(plainImage, blurredImage);
        Scene scene = new Scene(new ScrollPane(partiallyBlurredImage));
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    private ImageView createImageView() {
        ImageView imageView = new ImageView(image);
        imageView.setFitWidth(width);
        imageView.setFitHeight(height);
        imageView.setPreserveRatio(true);
        return imageView ;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

[image]